# Switching from zsh to bash on OS X, and back again?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I'm learning to develop in Rails, and have discovered the power of `zsh`. However, for some of my other tasks, I wish to use normal `bash`.

Although they are the same, I just feel comfortable with the layout of `bash` in some situations.

How do I switch back and forth, or turn `zsh` on and off?

Answer (score 651, accepted):

You can just use `exec` to replace your current shell with a new shell:

Switch to `bash`:

```
exec bash
```

Switch to `zsh`:

```
exec zsh
```

This won't affect new terminal windows or anything, but it's convenient.

Comment: Or, just invoke zsh, and when you’re done `exit` to get back to bash. Exec’ing it seems unnecessary and undesirable.

Comment: All depends on what you expect your terminal window to do when you exit.  I find starting a subshell unnecessary and undesirable, myself.

Comment: How do you change the default? Also, when I do "exec bash" in zsh, it does not source my bash_profile.

Comment: There are times when I want to use zsh and other times when it interferes with what I want to do.  Setting the default back and forth is a bad idea so this is the perfect solution!!! kudos!!

Comment: But if you run `echo $SHELL` it keep saying `/bin/zsh`, which have unexpected results like [this problem with MC (bug 3580)](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3580).

Comment: @kalehv `chsh -s /bin/zsh` will change the default. to source any executable including your .bash_profile do `. {filename}`

Answer (score 243):

you can try `chsh -s /bin/bash` to set the `bash` as the default,
or `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to set the `zsh` as the default.

Terminal will need a restart to take effect.

Comment: Not entirely true. One can simply enter command: "bash", or "zsh" to use that shell.

Comment: I don't think this work anymore in 2022

Answer (score 86):

I switch between zsh and bash somewhat frequently. For a while, I used to have to source my bash_profile every switch. Then I found out you can (typically) do

```
exec bash --login
```

or just

```
exec bash -l
```

Comment: Thanks phill, I installed thoughtbot/laptop and it mess all my configs. Your tip helps to get my bash environment back.

Comment: Would be useful hat you wrote what is "--login" for?

Comment: `Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).` [Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 22):

if it is just a temporary switch

you can use exec as mentioned above, but for more of a permanent solution.

you can use **chsh -s /bin/bash** (to switch to bash) and **chsh -s /bin/zsh** (to switch to zsh)

Comment: Mine is zsh right now but when I try chsh -s /bin/bash and type my password it show no changes made

Answer (score 21):

For Bash, try

```
chsh -s $(which bash)
```

For zsh, try

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

Answer (score 8):

In Mac OS Catalina default interactive shell is zsh. 
To change shell to zsh from bash:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Then you need to enter your Mac password. Quit the terminal and reopen it. To check whether it's changed successfully to ssh, issue the following command.

```
echo $SHELL
```

If the result is /bin/zsh, your task is completed.

To change it back to bash, issue the following command on terminal.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Verify it again using `echo $SHELL`. Then result should be /bin/bash.

Answer (score 6):

zsh has a builtin command `emulate` which can emulate different shells by setting the appropriate options, although csh will never be fully emulated.

```
emulate bash
perform commands
emulate -R zsh
```

The -R flag restores all the options to their default values for that shell.

See: [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html)

Comment: Not clear though what version of bash it will emulate, will it emulate bash 4.x? or 5.x?

Answer (score 6):

you can just type `bash` or if you always want to use bash:

on "iTerm2"

- Go to preferences > Profiles > Command
- Select "Command" from the dropdown
- Type `bash`

Test by closing iTerm and open it again

Answer (score 6):

Follow the below steps:

`chsh -s /bin/bash`
Restart terminal
Check which shell is in use: `echo $SHELL`
`source .profile`

You are back with Bash!

Comment: Users need to wait little bit before Restart terminal

Answer (score 4):

You should be able just to type `bash` into the terminal to switch to bash, and then type `zsh` to switch to zsh. Works for me at least.

Comment: This is even simpler.

Comment: This does work, but each time you type `zsh` or `bash` you are going into a sub-shell (subprocess under current shell).  You will need to type exit a number of times to return to the top-most shell.

Comment: this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this also via the UI by the following steps.

**Step 1**: Go to Preferences -> Users & Groups

**Step 2**: Select the user and press the unlock button and follow by entering the password

**Step 3**: Right click on the user and then select Advanced Options

**Step 4**: Select **/bin/bash** as the Login Shell

[image]

**Note**: You need to restart the shell to take this into effect.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was this:

Edit:

```
sudo vi /etc/passwd
```

Find your user, for me it was for example:

```
ubuntu:x:1000:1001::/home/ubuntu:/bin/sh
```

For you it might be:

```
ubuntu:x:1000:1001::/home/ubuntu:/bin/zsh
```

**And change it to**:

```
ubuntu:x:1000:1001::/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
```

If you want `bash` to be defaul, or the line above if you want it to be `zsh` by default.

Answer (score -8):

You can easily switch back to bash by using command "bye"

Comment: bye will exit zsh but not back to bash