# shopt command not found in .bashrc after shell updation

Tags: bash, sh, zshrc, shopt

I have updated my shell to ZSH. When I `source ~/.bashrc`. I am getting this error

There was some error in yo doctor .
when i execute this command

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

> /home/amerrnath/.bashrc:17: command not found: shopt
> /home/amerrnath/.bashrc:25: command not found: shopt
> /home/amerrnath/.bashrc:109: command not found: shopt
> /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:35: parse error near `]]'

Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: `zsh` is not `bash`. Why would you source `.bashrc`?

Comment: Your `bashrc` file was written for `bash`. `zsh` is not bash. I'm surprised it is trying to load your `.bashrc` at all. If it isn't and you are sourcing it manually from `.profile` or similar. Stop. Then replace it with an appropriate `zsh` init file.

Comment: post that as an answer

Comment: can you tell me the source of this error

Comment: I just wannted to add export a path and source a bash . but when i execute it shows this error

Comment: No, you *don't* want to source `~/.bashrc`. You want to figure out how to write a `~/.zshrc` file that does the same thing in `zsh` that `.bashrc` does in `bash`.

Comment: If you want to switch to bash you can execute `bash` and then execute `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 179, accepted):

zsh uses env profile `~/.zshrc`, not `~/.bashrc`.

so you need to append your env settings to `.zshrc` file and then

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

It must work.

[rbenv github link](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Comment: This doesn't explain why `shopt` worked in bach (because that it's not a bash built-in). @Omnipresence's answer is more informative.

Comment: You don't need to `source .zshrc` since it is loaded automatically with `zsh`.

Comment: Yes, but if you wanna load the new config immediately under current context, you need refresh it.

Comment: The output of my `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/zsh`, my `.zshrc` is in place. All of `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile/` & `/etc/bashrc` r completely commented out. Defaul shell is `zsh`, macOS is latest (Catalina 10.15.4) but I am still facing this exact problem whenever I run any `pyenv` command. I tried changing default shell to `bash` and same problem occured there too. Does this mean my OS is corrupted? [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478739/pyenv-giving-shopt-command-not-found-error-on-macos)

Comment: @saadi add the path of `pyenv` to .zshrc file.

Comment: @sudoz as I have updated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61478739/10190191), I already have added the path. `penv` is at `/usr/local/bin/` and that directory is already added in path that's why I am not getting `pyenv` command not found, instead, `shopt` command not found.

Answer (score 84):

To place anything in ~/.bashrc:

**Switch to bash:**

```
exec bash
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Switching to bash will not effect on new terminal window. But if you want to switch current window to zsh.

**Switch to zsh:**

```
exec zsh
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341338/1222852)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer according to me since some of the settings are being handled by the software installing and not me personally

Comment: Thank you for a time saver :)

Comment: Can I just switch by using `bash` keyword?

Comment: I mentioned exec bash above to switch to bash. But if only using bash works then it is ok

Comment: Excelent @TaimoorChangaiz. Thanks!

Comment: If all we need is to run bash sometimes, this solution will be the best.

Comment: Ohh my god. 
This answer saved me from thousands of problems
thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 68):

`shopt` is not a command, but a shell built-in. `bash` knows what to do with it because it's a `bash` built-in , but zsh has no idea what it is. You'll want to look into `setopt` which is a `zsh` built-in, and put those values into a new .zshrc script.

Comment: can you help me how to use setopt for this shopt

Comment: That's not a simple request. Your .bashrc file has at least 109 lines, and I don't know how many of them are comments or whitespace. I can only suggest that you look through your .bashrc file to figure out what it's doing, then find out how to do the same thing in zsh. If you've never customized your `.bashrc`, then maybe all you need it to change your command to: `echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question! Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Make an alias of shopt and call it through zsh

A quick solution is described here: https://github.com/larz258/Zshopt

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/shopt
```

Inside the shopt

```
#!/bin/bash
args='';
for item in $@
  do
    args="$args $item";
  done
shopt $args;
```

make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/shopt
```

Create an alias in your .zshrc

```
echo "alias shopt='/usr/bin/shopt'" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 11):

Your `bashrc` file was written for `bash`. `zsh` is not `bash`.

I'm surprised `zsh` is trying to load your `.bashrc` at all.

If it isn't and you are sourcing it manually (from `.profile` or similar). Stop doing that.

Then you get to write an appropriate `zsh` init file instead.

If you want to use `zsh` then you need to use `zsh` and not `bash`.

`shopt` is a bash-ism.

`[[` is a bash-ism.

Comment: echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc. When i execute this command in my shell i get this error

Comment: @user1475089 Yes, because your `.bashrc` file contains things that aren't legal `zsh`. You need to stop doing that. If you want that export in your `zsh` shell you stick that in your `zsh` init file and not `.bashrc`.

Comment: can explain you me in bit detail

Comment: @user1475089 You are trying to use `bash` built-in functionality in `zsh`. That works only marginally worse than trying to use a fork to eat soup. You need to stop using a fork to eat your soup and start learning how to use a spoon. (Go read up about `zsh` and how to do the things you want with it... or stop using `zsh` and go back to using `bash.)

Answer (score 6):

`shopt` is not a command, but a shell built-in. You can find out this by running the following command in bash：

```
type shopt
```

output would be:

```
shopt is a shell builtin
```

#### solution:

**step1:**

```
echo "#! /bin/bash\n\nshopt \$*\n" > /usr/local/bin/shopt
```

then you will get /usr/local/bin/shopt:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt $*
```

**step2:**

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/shopt
```

**step3:**

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/shopt /usr/bin/shopt
```

**step4:**

```
echo "alias shopt='/usr/bin/shopt'" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time will be that your are trying to execute a bash command within the zsh shell

swich to bash with
`exec bash` or

`bash`

Then go ahead and type
`source .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason after the upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 and to 18.04, the symlink /bin/sh was set back to dash not bash. Updating this link:

```
sudo cd /bin && ln -sf bash sh
```

solved this problem for me

Comment: Found this after searching for a reason why I didn't get history and cmd completion in terminal through few steps. HISTFILE -sh: history: not found was one of them. It apeard after adding user to Ubuntu server. I hope this line helps others find it quicker...