# pyenv giving shopt command not found error on macos

Tags: python, macos, zsh, zshrc, pyenv

I have been using `pyenv` for managing python versions and virtual environments on my mac for some time now.
Recently I reinstalled `pyenv` and since then on every `pyenv` command I try to run, I get the following error

```
/usr/local/bin/pyenv:94: command not found: shopt
```

My default shell is the latest `MacOS`'s default shell i.e. `zsh`.
On searching for the fix, I found out it has something to do with `bash` interfering with the `zsh`. 
My default shell is `zsh` in settings, the contents of `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` & `/etc/bashrc` are all commented out but I am still having the issue.
My OS Verion is: `10.15.4`.
I tried reinstalling `pyenv` as well but I am getting the same error.
I am unable to run ANY `pyenv` related command.

### Edit 1

I already have these lines in my `.zshrc` as per the documentation, but as you can see, even this run a command `pyenv root` and this gives me the same `shopt` error.

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$(pyenv root)/shims:$(pyenv root)/completions/pyenv.zsh:$PATH"
```

### Edit 2

> Run `env` and add the output in your question

```
TMPDIR=/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=433
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
TERM_SESSION_ID=55A65E3A-9B71-4C8A-81B8-0170EEAE3DCE
TERM=xterm-256color
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.j6zkqCw6Of/Listeners
SHELL=/bin/zsh
HOME=/Users/abc
LOGNAME=abc
USER=abc
PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/Users/saadali/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.16/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/abc/bin:/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin
SHLVL=1
PYTHONPATH=
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
port=
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

### Edit 3

Please read [this](https://gitter.im/yyuu/pyenv) chat first before recommending to try something, as I might have already tried it. Chat starts at `Apr 29 02:01 UTC +5` and then moves to a thread.

### Edit 4

After setting `PYENV_DEBUG=1`, here the output

```
(vmds) saadali@A006-00276 ~ :~$ pyenv
+ [:22] enable -f /../libexec/pyenv-realpath.dylib realpath
+ [:29] [ -z '' ']'
+ [:31] READLINK=+ [:31] type -p greadlink readlink
+ [:31] READLINK=+ [:31] head -1
+ [:31] READLINK='greadlink not found' 
+ [:32] [ -n 'greadlink not found' ']'
+ [:57] [ -z '' ']'
+ [:58] PYENV_ROOT=/Users/abc/.pyenv 
+ [:62] export PYENV_ROOT
+ [:65] [ -z '' ']'
+ [:66] [ -n '' ']'
+ [:82] [ -z '' ']'
+ [:83] PYENV_DIR=/Users/abc 
+ [:86] [ ! -d /Users/abc ']'
+ [:86] [ ! -e /Users/abc ']'
+ [:90] PYENV_DIR=+ [:90] cd /Users/abc
+ [:90] echo /Users/abc
+ [:90] PYENV_DIR=/Users/abc 
+ [:91] export PYENV_DIR
+ [:94] shopt -s nullglob
/usr/local/bin/pyenv:94: command not found: shopt
```

Comment: What's the first line of `/usr/local/bin/pyenv`?

Comment: What's the output of `which shopt`?

Comment: Run `env` and add the output of the same to your question

Comment: @MarkSetchell first line is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but this problem happens in bash terminal too.

Comment: @con-- `shopt` is an internal `bash` command, on `zsh` output of `which shopt` is of course command not found, on `bash` terminal it returns nothing as it's not a command, but if I do simple `shopt`, it shows some shopt related stuff.

Comment: @TarunLalwani done.

Comment: @saadi Is `/usr/bin/env bash` *really* executing `/usr/bin/bash`? What happens if you change the shebang in your pyenv executable to `#!/usr/bin/bash`? Also, remember you can run *pyenv* with debug output by setting `PYENV_DEBUG=1`.

Comment: @amain added the debug output in question. Also, changing `/usr/bin/env bash` to `/bin/bash` worked for me. But to made it work, I had to change my default terminal shell to `bash` instead of `zsh` and I had been using it with `zsh` and it used to work fine. Also, running `/usr/bin/evn bash` works fine in my `zsh` terminal.

Comment: So it wasn't working properly, like `pyenv --version` worked but `pyenv ls` did not work, I did `$ which bash` and then seeing the output, I did `ls -l /usr/local/bin/bash` which showed me a symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/bash -> /bin/zsh` should this link be here? Also making the change in the above comment made some commands work and some not, what kind of behaviour is this?

Comment: @saadi For me, this looks like some broken `bash` command, e.g. some wrong symlinks? That said, *pyenv* should work fine (at least not choke on *shopt*) when you invoke it directly with `/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/pyenv`.

Comment: I THINK it will work if I somehow break that link but I am also scared of the repercussions as it might break many other things. Is there a solution besides reinstalling OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your info and comments it seems your issue has 3 causes working hand in hand:

1. *pyenv* is a *bash* (and *bash*-only) script with a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
2. `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` or `/bin` in your PATH, so executables therein are picked up first by `/usr/bin/env` (desired behaviour, especially when using *homebrew*)
3. `/usr/local/bin/bash` is symlinked to `/bin/zsh`!?!

So in the end you are running *pyenv* with *zsh*, which, albeit being a close replacement for *bash*, doesn't know about *shopt* and therefore chokes. I don't know why the symlink is in place, but it shouldn't, because *zsh is not a fully compatible drop-in replacement for bash*.

I'd suggest to

1. *(in case you are using homebrew)*
   Check if you have/had `bash` installed through *homebrew* (which was later somehow replaced by a symlink to *zsh*):

   ```
   # shows only top-level packages (directly installed)
   brew leaves        

   # shows *all* packages with dependency tree
   brew deps --tree --installed
   ```

   And uninstall *bash* if not required anymore (which *should* then remove `/usr/local/bin/bash`).
2. Either delete or at least rename the culprit:

   `mv /usr/local/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash_link_to_zsh`

   Or, if some program requires `/usr/local/bin/bash` to be in place, just have it point to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: According to your observation#2 from comments, I re arranged my `PATH` and now it works fine thanks.