# Suddenly my terminal changed and started saying -zsh at the end and stopped working when using a file with pillow

Tags: python, linux, terminal, zsh

I was smoothly working on my terminal having a good time and suddenly I don't know exactly what I did but now instead of the prompt having the regular directory path it now displays (With a percentage sign that I had never seen before):

---

`emilio@Emilios-MacBook-Air-3 ~ %`.

It's so weird because it just suddenly changed and now I can't run my Files correctly. 
I was doing a project using Pillow and now the terminal prompts:

---

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

Before this, I was using the file perfectly in the terminal and it never displayed such an error. I already looked up the problem on the internet but coudn't find the solution.

Your help would be great

Comment: Note that in general, questions about terminal configuration are more likely to be on-topic at [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com); Stack Overflow is only for questions about *writing code*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upgrade to Catalina [apple replaced bash with zsh](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features)

I think the solution for you will depend on which python distribution you have but there are a few stack overflow questions already that deal with this for the conda distribution, e.g. [Conda not found after upgrading to macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291108/conda-not-found-after-upgrading-to-macos-catalina)
 and [Can't find pip, conda, python modules after OSX Catalina update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315341/cant-find-pip-conda-python-modules-after-osx-catalina-update)

Even if you are using another distribution, there might be something in there that is useful.

You may also be able to temporary or permanently [switch back to bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341271/switching-from-zsh-to-bash-on-osx-and-back-again/10341338) with something like `exec bash -l`

Comment: @EmilioAndere if this answer solved your problem, remember to accept it and upvote

Comment: Yeah, went right in to fix it and totally forgot about it, but thanks.